# Сезон Шляп 2017: только лучшие шляпы!

Tags: поддержка, новогодние-шляпы

<sub>Свободный перевод публикации из блога [Winter Bash 2017: Greatest <strike>Hits</strike> Hats!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats/)</sub>

---

С каждым градусом ниже нуля в северном полушарии мы приближаемся к Новому году. На Stack Overflow и других сайтах сети Stack Exchange ушки тысяч участников и участниц начинают подмерзать. А это значит, что настала пора согреть их … с помощью шляп!

[image]

В этот раз только избранное: в честь 6-й годовщины Сезона шляп<sup>1</sup> некоторые из самых полюбившихся шляп прошлых лет выступят на бис. Мы постарались настроить шляпы так, чтобы обеспечить максимальное веселье! (Ну а если вы соскучитесь, то всегда сможете отправиться на поиск новых шляп, ожидающих когда же их разыщут!)

[image]

Готовьтесь к зрелищным развлечениям и хорошему настроению!

Примите участие в [соревнованиях](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com) [на сайтах-участниках](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network), чтобы получить шляпу и красоваться в ней везде, где отображается изображение из вашей учетной записи. Как только вы получаете новую шляпу, вы можете выбрать ее среди заработанных шляп в вашем профиле на любом из сайтов сети. Для этого просто нажмите на значок-шапку в разделе знаков для вызова меню выбора шляп.

[image]

Нажав на это изображение, вы увидите специальное меню.

[image]

При выборе шляпы вы можете изменить ее размер или расположение на изображении профиля, чтобы она точно подошла именно вам.

[image]

Сезон шляп — это уникальная возможность раз в год расслабиться и немного повеселиться всем вместе на Stack Overflow и других сайтах сети Stack Exchange. 
Но даже в сезон, когда мы прячем наши прически, надевая шляпы, мы крайне уважительно относимся к коллегам, которые предпочитают, чтобы их опыт на Stack Overflow и Stack Exchange был как можно более профессиональным: вы можете отказаться от участия в Сезоне шляп, выбрав «Я ненавижу шляпы» из меню «Снежинки» в верхней панели сайта.

Что касается всех остальных: с сегодняшнего дня (13 декабря 2017 года) и до 2 января 2018 года мы постараемся открыть все шляпы! Как обычно, по завершению сезона шляпы отправляются в дальний чулан, чтобы их больше никто никогда не надел ... если только лучшие шляпы не появятся снова через <strike>5</strike> 6 лет! Вот так!

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Забавный факт: авторы Сезона шляп хотели отпраздновать лучшими шляпами пятую годовщину, но, как оказалось после [подсчета](https://stackpromos.com), это уже шестой зимний праздник. Получается, авторы Сезона шляп, как и все мы, подвержены ошибке [неучтённой единицы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83).</sub>

Comment: Опять шляпа (((

Comment: @HamSter Подскажите, пожалуйста, вы про что именно вы говорите?

Comment: О том, что еще один год шляп, а не елочек или еще чего-нибудь для разнообразия)

Comment: @HamSter В прошлом году было [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDi_nj1-G6U), объясняющее почему именно шляпы, а не что–то другое.

Comment: cделайте сохранение шляп, чтобы заработанное раньше можно было одевать на след нг

Answer (score 8):

Если честно, не понимаю: почему Новый Год и шляпы? Ну, ладно бы это были: борода, морковка вместо носа, ведро на голову или колпак эльфа, мешок с подарками и т.п. Неужели стало лень поменять графику?

Comment: Потому что в новый год наступает шляпа)

Comment: Возможно, одна из причин в том, что на SO огромное количество представителей тех культул, которые не празднуют Новый Год и не имеют соответствующих мифологических фигур или имеют в корне отличающиеся.

Comment: Зимние шапки тоже далеко не у всех в ходу ввиду отсутствия снега :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov тут я соглашусь, последние дни +12 - +14, не уверен, будет ли снег на НГ. По крайней мере шапки точно никто не носит.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov шапки могут и от жары защищать )

Comment: @ViktorTomilov на этот случай среди "шляп" есть причёска в стиле "афро" :)